# Show attachment in Sharepoint linked list

Tags: list, sharepoint, linked-list, attachment

I linked two SharePoint lists. They are joined by column ID (like a foreign key).

When I click the Display Item of List #2, it also includes the fields of List #1.

But I can't figure out how to display the attachment from List #1. Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you displaying this data in a standard List View configured via the browser? Using a Data View web part configured via SharePoint Designer? Writing your own CAML & creating a visual web part? More info on what you're doing & what you've tried will ensure better answers.

Comment: The two SharePoint lists are joined using a Linked Data Source. I created a Joined Subview in List #2 then I selected a column that acts a foreign key between both lists. 

Now I am able to display fields of List #1 in the DisplayForm.aspx of List #2. But I would like to show the attachment from List #1 too. Is that possible?